# OpenCV dnn exception SSD Mobilenetv2

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, mobilenet, dotnetnuke, tensorflow-ssd

Using transfer learning, I trained SSD MobileNetV2 (ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config) model in TensorFlow (tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0). After freezing the graph (.pb) using TensorFlow API Python script (export_inference_graph.py), I created a text graph (.pbtxt) using the Python script provided in OpenCV wiki (tf_text_graph_ssd.py).

I used the Python code snippet from the wiki to test inference, but I am getting the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:562: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_2/add" of type "AddV2" in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20191202::LayerData::getLayerInstance'
```

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.6.8, and OpenCV 4.2.0.32. I have tried downgrading OpenCV, but earlier versions give different errors.

However, in Ubuntu 18.04.4, installing OpenCV from source, I do not get any errors. Does anybody know if this is an incompatible layer in binary wheels of OpenCV for Windows? Should I wait until the next release?